# Swift: Return Backendless to table

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, backendless

Im having a problem on putting my received data(from backendless) to a tableview. 
As you can see on the image i have get data from Backendless and i have checked the data with print and it works. 
Now i want to put the data to my tableView, but it does not work as you usually do with making an array in the beginning and then just put return.Sub.count.

Any idea how to do it?

[image: My code]

Comment: Why don't declare Sub array globally? After insert data into array then reload the table.

Comment: I have tried @Md.MuzahidulIslam . If i have done it right... Putting var Sub = [String]() in the top and right under "var Sub = [Subjectsm Sub.... bla bla] i put self.tableView.reloadData.

Comment: This is a scope issue - I would suggest reading up about programming and scope in general to get a better idea why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare

```
var Sub  = [String]()
```

underneath your tableView class declaration (At the very top)

Then, in your function,

```
fetchingAllUsers()
```

delete the "var" keyword, and you should be fine.

Also, it'd help if you posted all of your code if you need me to be more specific.

Comment: Also, make sure fetchingAllUsers() Gets called before Returning your numberOfRowsInSections